# Adding CORS support to AWS API Gateway endpoints

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Reading the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html

It's not clear to me that specifying CORS on an endpoint means that it only applies to that level, or all the sub-resources as well?

F.e.,

let's say I add a method at resource path - /products and

```
declare const productsResource: apigateway.Resource;

productsResource.addCorsPreflight({
  allowOrigins: [ 'https://amazon.com' ],
  allowMethods: [ 'GET', 'PUT' ]

Does that apply to /products/{productdId} as well?
});
```

Or do I need a separate addCorsPreflight() call for that sub-resource?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how that sub resource is defined.

If it is an actual Resource, i believe the answer is yes - you do need to define it for all other *defined* resources. Doing this for any given resource that is **NOT a proxy** connection will enable the OPTIONS method on your resource.

However if its a Proxy end point (which as a product ID i would expect) linked to a lambda it has to handle the Cors Preflight response itself.

Youd have to, for instance, (NOT working code, you need to define how to know if this is a preflight or not based on the incoming event from Api Gateway that triggers the lambda)

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    if preflight:
       return response;
};
```

Find more information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html